Keep python click argument case
Using the following click application:
from rich.traceback import install

install(show_locals=True)

import click


@click.command()
@click.argument("PATH", envvar="PATH", nargs=-1, type=click.Path())
def f1(PATH):
    print(PATH)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f1()

I get the following error:
TypeError: f1() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

How can I force click to keep the argument case?

Why do you want to keep the case?

I'm creating something similar to typer, and I'd like uppercased variables to use environment variables as their defaults.

By setting case_sensitive=True, Click will preserve the case of the argument names. This should resolve the TypeError you encountered.
from rich.traceback import install

install(show_locals=True)

import click


@click.command(case_sensitive=True)  # Set case_sensitive=True
@click.argument("PATH", envvar="PATH", nargs=-1, type=click.Path())
def f1(PATH):
    print(PATH)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    f1()


That seems to be giving me a TypeError: Command.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'case_sensitive' error.
